# CodeIgniter Pagination

Tags: php

I have a little trouble with code igniter, I work since 4h this morning, my brain is in off mode.

I have this code,

```
public function books($Page = 0)
    {
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('user/books');
        //Recherche des livres
        $SubSearch = $this->input->post('SubSearch');
        //Nombre occurence par page
        $SubPerPage = $this->input->post('SubPerPage');
        //Configuration du mode d'affichage de tout les livres
            //Gestion du champ de recherche
                if(isset($SubSearch))
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('BookSearch',$this->input->post('Search'));
                }
            //Gestion du nombre par page
                if(isset($SubPerPage))
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('PerPage',$this->input->post('PerPage'));
                }

            //Gestion nombre affichage per page
            if(!empty($this->session->userdata('PerPage')))
                    {
                        $config['per_page'] = $this->session->userdata('PerPage'); 
                    }else
                    {
                        $config['per_page'] = 10;
                    }
            //La Requette
                if(!empty($this->session->userdata('BookSearch')))
                {
                    $config['total_row'] = $this->functions->getSearch($this->session->userdata('BookSearch'),"","")->num_rows();
                    $query = $this->functions->getSearch($this->session->userdata('BookSearch'),$Page,$config['per_page']);
                }else
                {
                    $config['total_row'] = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM books')->num_rows();
                    $query = 'SELECT * FROM books LIMIT '.$Page.','.$config['per_page'].'';
                    $query = $this->db->query($query);
                }

                $data['BooksSearchQuery'] = $query->result();
                echo 'perpage : '.$config['per_page'];
                echo 'total row : '.$config['total_row'];
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $this->load->view('user/books',$data);
    }
```

But the create_links gives nothing, while the values

```
echo 'perpage : '.$config['per_page'];
echo 'total row : '.$config['total_row'];
```

are good.
A solution? thank you by advance

Comment: Does $data['BooksSearchQuery'] have any rows? Try var_dump on it first.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, var_dump on BooksSearchQuery tell me i have 10 size, it's all right.

Comment: If you have only 10 rows and your config is set to 10 then there are no links to create.  Try setting the config to 5.   `$config['per_page'] = 5;`

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand that on CodeIgniter the class of Pagination just allows to output a limit for the query. Hence the Total Row.
The page count is the calculation between $ config ['per_page'] and $ config ['total_row']
Example if total_row = 20 and per_page = 10 then NbPage = 2
Do you understand?
When we change page, we send in a get the limit of the sql request.

SELECT * FROM book LIMIT $ RelatedPage, $ PerPage. And this request : SELECT * FROM books contain 20 row normalely

Comment: What is the value of $config['total_row'] = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM books')->num_rows();

If it is less than 10 then no pagination. More than 10, pagination should happen.

Comment: @L.Ayrton Did you fix your issue?  Did my input help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 10 rows and your config is set to 10 then there are no links to create.  Try setting the config to 5.   `$config['per_page'] = 5;`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, a stupid mistake.

```
$ Config ['total_row'];
```

must be

```
$ Config ['total_rows'];
```

Really stupid! thank you very much

Comment: i have worte the tutorial about Codeigniter Pagination. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/. Have a look and give your suggestions